# Targeting google map tiles within an iframe to change their opacity using jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, opacity, tiles

Basically as the title says I am wanting to use jQuery to taget the google map tiles inside an iframe.

Any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! [What have you tried to do in code?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have tried $('div.gm-map iframe div#geo-mashup div').css('opacity','0.8'); But when realising that wouldn't work I asked if there was a way to target the div inside the iframe. I have since learnt that that is not possible to do. So now I guess I have to find a different solution... Unless you have any suggestions.